# How to find the most recent date within a group

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a table with a list of sales of items by customer and date, as below.

[image]

I would like to write some function(s) to find the **most recent date of sales number by each item and customer**, without using a pivot table.

My expected output is:

[image]

Any tip/suggestion is appreciated.

Comment: Use `MAXIFS` formula to get the most recent date i.e. `=MAXIFS(DateColumn,ItemCol,ItemCrit,CustomerCol,CustomerCrit)`. Replace the fields with actual column references!

Comment: *I would like to write some function* And what have you tried until now? Because you said you want to write, but right now it sounds kind of *write for me*

Comment: Thanks for sharing the maxifs function. I tried to use it by myself and it worked as what I have expected.

Answer (score 2):

In `H2`, formula copied right to `I2`, and all copied down:

```
=LOOKUP(9^9,C$2:C$11/($A$2:$A$11=$F2)/($B$2:$B$11=$G2))
```

[image]

Edit :

Since the Lookup formula will return the last date match, column C (date) should be sorted in ascending order.

Comment: I think you should mention that the data must be sorted from oldest to newest.